# JavaScript If statement issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new here, and this is the first question to be asked by me.

I'm a beginner in programming and coding, I'm trying to make a basic system to view students' marks by entering their school numbers. 
Here's my code:-

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<input type="text" id="txtjob">
<button onclick="getnatega()">OK</button>


<script>
function getnatega() {
if (txtjob == 2386) {
window.location.href = "www.ex.com";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But whenever i click the "OK" button nothing happens. 
I'd be thankful to whoever helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `document` API to get reference to the element in JavaScript. You can assign that element to a variable so you don't have to call the method every time.

```
var txtJob = document.getElementById('txtjob');
function getnatega() {
  if (txtJob.value == '2386') {
    window.location.href = "www.ex.com";
  }
}
```

There is a quirk in some browsers where the engine will define a global variable with the ID of the element. You may be able to get away with just `if (window.txtjob.value == '2386')` but even if it works I don't recommend using it because it's not a standardized behavior and all browsers may not do the same thing. All of them will have the `document` API though and you can use that to properly get reference to the element as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the element itself and take the value out of it. The result is a string.

```js
function getnatega() {
    if (document.getElementById('txtjob').value === '2386') {
        window.location.href = "www.ex.com";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtjob">
<button onclick="getnatega()">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getnatega() 
{
  var a=document.getElementById('txtjob').value;

  if ( a == 2386) 
  {
    window.location.href = "www.ex.com";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="txtjob">
<button onclick="getnatega()">OK</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks sound to me?

Comment: Since the result is string and you use non quoted `2386` it shouldn't, if to use `===`, which I missed you didn't ... removed comment and down vote

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because `txtjob` is undefined. If you want to get the input's value, it's in `document.getElementById("txtjob").value`.

Comment: It is more than enough. Asker should do some work, I prefer to explain than to give code to copy and paste.